# React state is undefined after assigning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./app.css";
import Header from "./components/header";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.initState();
  }

  initState = () => {
    this.getMostPopularVideos().then(result => {
      this.setState({ contents: result });
      console.log(result);  // data is OK here.
    });
  }

  getMostPopularVideos = async () => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      redirect: 'follow'
    };

    const res = await fetch(<query path>, requestOptions)

    let contents;
    if (res.ok) {
      contents = await res.json();
    } else {
      alert(`HTTP-Error: ${res.status}`);
      contents = { a: { b: "test"}};
    }

    return contents;
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render', this.props, this.state);
    return (
      <>
        <Header/>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The code fetches data from an APIs and assign it to state.

But after assign, this.state is undefined.

I tried to assign directly without setState, the result was same.

What's the problem?

**[Update]**

I've studied React lifecycle and updated the code, here is it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./app.css";
import Header from "./components/header";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {contents: null};
  }

  initState = () => {
    this.getMostPopularVideos()
      .then(result => this.setState({ contents: result }));
  }

  getMostPopularVideos = async () => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      redirect: 'follow'
    };

    const res = await fetch(<query path>, requestOptions)

    let contents;
    if (res.ok) {
      contents = await res.json();
    } else {
      alert(`HTTP-Error: ${res.status}`);
      contents = { a: { b: "test"}};
    }

    return contents;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initState()
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render', this.props, this.state);
    return (
      <>
        <Header/>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I moved asynchronous logic into `componentDidMount()`,

but still have problems.

Checkers say `this.state` contains data what I fetched,

1. Components (Chrome extension)
2. `console.log(this.state)` statement in `render()` - after 2nd render(because of `setState`)

while after render when I type `console.log(this.state)` in chrome console, it returns `undefined`.

This situation is very weird.

Is there any hint for this?

Comment: you should not have any side effect in the constructor all side effect should go in `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your modified code with a placeholder API as:

```js
const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
```

And it worked for me.

To answer your question of why you could not see the value of `this.state` when you type it in the chrome console:

If you try to see the value of `this.state` in Chrome console by doing, `console.log(this.state)`, you'll get `undefined` because for Chrome console, `this` would be the global `window` variable which represents the window in which the script is running that is: [Window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)

You can check that the value of `this` is the `Window` object by doing `console.log(this)` in the Chrome console.